# Format the TimeSpan string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timespan, monthcalendar

I have a small C# program that has a calendar and 7 labels. When I select a date the labels display the days and dates of that week.

The labels are populated using the `TimeSpan` string what I want to do is format this string so that it only displays the days and dates with out the times.

This is the code I have so far:

```
        private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dTime = new DateTime();
            dTime = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
            dTime -= new TimeSpan((int)dTime.DayOfWeek, 0, 0, 0 );

            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                var dt = dTime.AddDays(i);
                lb[i].Text = dt.DayOfWeek + " : " + dt.Date;                         
            }           
        }
```

Comment: you can use like this also lb[i].Text =dt.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options.

You can use `ToShortDateString()` method for the `DateTime` type

```
lb[i].Text = dt.DayOfWeek + " : " + dt.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

or you can provide of a format to the `ToString("format")` method to specify exactly what you want it to look like.

```
lb[i].Text = dt.DayOfWeek + " : " + dt.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I like the second solution more seem more flexible.

Comment: @Tacit: Depends on your needs. The first solution has the advantage to adjust to the user's culture. For example, in french, month/day/year is not natural, because in french speak the date is in day/month/year order. The first solution would display day/month/year to a french user.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `dt.Date.ToShortDateString()`.

Comment: Thanks that did the job. I feel so stupid to not trying that :s

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`DateTime.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) method;

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   short date string representation.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
label8.Text = dt.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

You can learn more details from [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)